# iPhone app sugesion

Tags: objective-c, movie

in India we have movie culture where every movie has 5 to 6 songs.  We have copy rights and distribution rights for the songs of the some movies. What I want to know is can we make an app which has the only the audio songs in it. So that fans of that movie can download the app and listen to the music of that movie. We will provide the songs along with the app itself , without the users having to stream from the Internet. Before we start off with making of the ap we need to know if apple allows such kind of app. Has any one seen such an app before. I am not sure how to contact apple to ask the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an app is possible: see things like the Napoleon Dynamite soundboard app, it's an app that just plays sounds.

The main problem is though, the user would probably expect to have the music in their music collection as well. Are you sure that is the best way?